# Not able to connect incoming caller to th dialed calee in meetme function in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, phone-call

My code is simple A calls to B the they both entered into meetme conference

```
[from-pstn]
exten=> _X.,n,Answer()
same => n,dial(DAHDI/g0/0${9xxxxxxxxx},20,mM(MYCONFO))

[macro-MYCONFO]
exten => s,n,Meetme(1234,sdrM)
```

But when A calls to B only B enters the conference and A is not able to enter conference , A only hears musiconhold

yes i have read [meetme](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MeetMe) and [n way dialout](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+n-way+call+HOWTO)

Can anybody help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for this you should use option G from DIAL command:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial

G(context^exten^pri): If the call is answered, transfer both parties to the specified context and extension. The calling party is transferred to priority x, and the called party to priority x+1. This allows the dialplan to distinguish between the calling and called legs of the call (new in v1.2). You cannot use any options that would affect the post-answer state if this option is used.

So dialplan should be:

```
[from-pstn]
exten=> _X.,n,Answer()
same => n,dial(DAHDI/g0/0${9xxxxxxxxx},20,mG(MYCONFO,s,1))
[MYCONFO]
exten => s,1,Meetme(1234,sdrM)
exten => s,2,Meetme(1234,sdr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is incorrect.

Please read again documentation about in-call-macro. It have alot of limits

Try use goto.

If not work, try use transfer from external application with UserEvent

ps. yes, it work as described in n-way-howto too.

Comment: why my code is incorrect?,this macro works for me in simple dial situation

Comment: Because you can't use Metmee in suspended call. It is  blocked unless you return from macro. In you macro you never return.